# Using a Regex as a template

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Regex:

```
var legal = /[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+/;
```

Which is supposed to define that the only **valid** strings are the ones made up of those characters inside `[]`, repeated a positive number of times.

And so, the following works fine:

```
legal.test("a"); // => true
legal.test("/"); // => false
```

However, this does not work fine:

```
legal.test("a/"); // => true
```

It should be false. I tried putting a `$` at the end of the ReGeX to signify end of line, and it helps, but not always:

```
var legal2 = /[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+$/;

legal2.test("a"); // => true
legal2.test("a/"); // => false
legal2.test("a/a"); // => true
```

The last one should be `false`, so the `$` in the end doesn't always help.

What do I need to do to my Regex to make it act like a "template" for which strings to be validated?

Comment: You were already half-way there. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+$/` (In other words - why only anchor it to the end?)

Comment: @Tomalak, [this should be an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/217110)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to indicate the start of the string matching by a caret (`^`) in front:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+$
```

This will now match only the strings containing only the allowed characters.

Your pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]+$` was matching the last `a` of `a/a` because you did not mention strictly where to start matching from but you did impose the end condition with `$`.